# PHP Date format conversion '/' to '-'

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I have date string

```
$date = '27/02/2015';
```

My desire output is **2015-02-27** So i tried this

`$newDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));`

But i was gives **1969-12-31**
Am i missed anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $date = '27/02/2015';
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $date);
    echo $d->format("Y-m-d");

?>
```

Output:

```
2015-02-27
```

Comment: It's working fine . But what 's the problem with / and - characters

Comment: @vijay4vijju The problem is `strtotime()` thinks that your format is US you can see this in the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) at the bottom under notes you can read about that (e.g. It looks at the separator so `/` -> america -> `m/d/y` that's why you get the wrong output)

Comment: Thanks now i got my problem

Answer (score 3):

Just explode this string:

```
list($d,$m,$y) = explode('/',$date);
```

And reconcatenate like:

```
$newDate = "$y-$m-$d";
```

Answer (score 1):

With `/` is not a standard date time format Try to replace it with `-`

```
$date = '27/02/2015';
echo $newDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date)));//2015-02-27
```

Comment: But it woks when '02/27/2015' even without replace